# Regular expression for 7 digit numbers separeted by commas

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need a regular expression to validate a concatenated string that consists of 7 digit numbers separated by commas.

Furthermore, I must ensure that:

- The string is not empty.
- The chain doesn't begins or finish with commas.
- The numbers do not start with 0.

Example: 1234567,2345678,3456789

My solution so far: `^\d+(,\d+)*?$`

**The problems I still need to resolve**:

- Validate that the numbers are exactly 7 digits.
- Validate that the numbers do not start with 0.

Thank you.

Comment: split on commas, check length

Answer (score 1):

Something like `^[1-9]\d{6}(,[1-9]\d{6})+$` should work. The `[1-9]` ensures the number doesn't begin with 0, and `\d{6}` ensures that there are 6 digits to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Gavin answer, here is what worked for me : `^[1-9]\d{6}(,[1-9]\d{6})*$`

The minor difference is the use of the * instead of + at the end of the regular expression. There are some cases where I must validate only one 7 digits number...

Thank you for the help everyone!